How to store templated argument in member function as member variable and invoke it later?
I am trying to make a MyWrapper struct which has a template function called set(). The set() function can take a callable as an argument. In my 3 use cases, they are:

lambda [...]() -> void{...} (move capturing one as well)
std::function<void()>
any callable class

I am not understanding how I can store the handle passed in as an argument of set() as a member variable in MyWrapper.
I don't want to use classes / base classes with virtual nor std::function<void()> inside of MyWrapper, nor do I want to make MyWrapper a template struct. Is there a way to do it?
I have been trying with the below code, but I am not understanding how to resolve saving the handle to savedHandler. Is my approach completely incorrect?
I am inspired from usage of boost asio timer functions, like async_wait(), which can take any kind of callable. But I am not understanding how to replicate it.
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67e9858d20b7dc73
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct MyWrapper{
    template <typename T>
    void set(T&& handle){
        using HandlerType = std::decay_t<T>;
        savedHandler = std::make_unique<HandlerWrapper<HandlerType>>(std::forward<T>(handle));
    }
    
    void invoke(){
        if (savedHandler){
           savedHandler->invoke(); 
        }
    }

    template<typename Callable>
    class HandlerWrapper {
    public:
        explicit HandlerWrapper(Callable&& handler)
            : handler_(std::move(handler)) {}

        void invoke() {
            handler_();
        }
    private:
        Callable handler_; 
    };

    std::unique_ptr<HandlerWrapper<void()>> savedHandler;
};

struct RandomStruct
{
    RandomStruct(std::unique_ptr<int>&& ptr)
        : ptr_(std::move(ptr)){}
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Handler invoked with value: " << *ptr_ << std::endl;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr_;
};


int main() {
    MyWrapper op;
    
    //  use case 1
    op.set([ptr = std::make_unique<int>(2)]() {
        std::cout << "Handler invoked with value: " << *ptr << std::endl;
    });
    op.invoke();
    
    //  use case 2
    RandomStruct rs(std::make_unique<int>(2));
    op.set(std::move(rs));
    op.invoke();

    return 0;
}


I donot want to use classes / base classes with virtual nor std::function<void()> inside of MyWrapper nor do i want to make MyWrapper struct a template struct. Is there a way to do it? If you stick to these conditions, and don't want to have any alternatives to std::function either, then answer is: no. There just no universal interface to call such different arguments.

Why do you not want to use std::function? I think anything you end up writing yourself is going to be pretty close to it.

your example, boost asio timer, uses a version of std::move_only_function , which is identical to std::function but it cannot be copied ....

This is exactly what std::function is designed for. Why don't you want to use it?

to answer your question. no, it is not possible, you either do dynamic dispatch with virtual or type-erasure with std::function or generic programming using templates, since you refused all 3 options then you have no other choice.

i didnot want to use std::function coz i thot it wont allow me to pass a lambda with unique_ptr since std::function needs to be copyable and including lambda in capture will make it non copyable. I was not aware that boost timer used a version of std::move_only_function.

you can usually just pass a shared_ptr to std::function to get around the copyable requirement if you don't have access to std::move_only_function, it is slower, but if you don't expect to call it a million times a second it should be fast enough.

@AhmedAEK i want to use any trick with templates but i donot want to convert MyWrapper to:
template 
struct MyWrapper{...}

@AhmedAEK i checked std::move_only_function and according to my understanding it is available in C++23 i am trying to find a solution for C++17.

I would really recommend you use std::move_only_function, or for C++17 find another verison of it online, it also goes by the name any_invocable, and available in multiple libraries online including google's abseil, even asio has a version called any_completetion_handler
A simplified implementation of std::move_only_function based on your code is as follows, the basic idea is that we type-erase everything behind void pointers and cast it back to our type on invocation or deletion.
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct MyWrapper {
    using erased_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<void, void(*)(void*)>;

    template <typename T>
    void set(T&& handle) {
        using HandlerType = std::decay_t<T>;
        m_object = erased_unique_ptr{ 
            static_cast<void*>(new HandlerType{std::forward<T>(handle)}),
            +[](void* ptr) {
            delete static_cast<T*>(ptr);
            } };
        
        m_func = +[](void* obj)
            {
                static_cast<T*>(obj)->operator()();
            };
    }

    using void_func_t = void(*)();
    void set(void_func_t handle) {
        m_object = erased_unique_ptr{
            reinterpret_cast<void*>(handle),
            +[](void*) {} };

        m_func = +[](void* obj)
            {
                reinterpret_cast<void_func_t>(obj)();
            };
    }

    MyWrapper() : m_object{ nullptr,+[](void*) {} }, m_func{ nullptr } {}
    MyWrapper(MyWrapper&&) = default;
    MyWrapper& operator=(MyWrapper&&) = default;

    void invoke() {
        if (m_object) {
            m_func(m_object.get());
        }
    }

    using func_type = void(*)(void*);
    erased_unique_ptr m_object;
    func_type m_func;
};

struct RandomStruct
{
    RandomStruct(std::unique_ptr<int>&& ptr)
        : ptr_(std::move(ptr)) {}
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Handler invoked with value: " << *ptr_ << std::endl;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr_;
};

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "free function" << '\n';
}

int main() {
    MyWrapper op;

    //  use case 1
    op.set([ptr = std::make_unique<int>(2)]() {
        std::cout << "Handler invoked with value: " << *ptr << std::endl;
        });
    op.invoke();

    //  use case 2
    RandomStruct rs(std::make_unique<int>(2));
    op.set(std::move(rs));
    op.invoke();

    op.set(hello);
    op.invoke();

    return 0;
}

godbolt demo
std::move_only_function and its different implementations offers a small buffer optimization, while others allow using custom allocators, which we just ignore in this super simplified implementation.
